# How to check if there is no message in RabbitMQ with Pika and Python

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, python-pika

I read messages from RabbitMQ with the pika python library. Reading messages in the loop is done by

```
connection = rpc.connect()
channel = connection.channel()
channel.basic_consume(rpc.consumeCallback, queue=FromQueue, no_ack=Ack)
channel.start_consuming()
```

This works fine.
But I also have the need to read one single message, which I do with:

```
method, properties, body = channel.basic_get(queue=FromQueue)
rpc.consumeCallback(Channel=channel,Method=method, Properties=properties,Body=body)
```

But when there is no message in the queue, the script is craching. How do I implement the get_empty() method described [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.get) ?

Comment: The `channel.start_consuming` is blocking. How can you call `channel.basic_get`? Are you using separate threads?

Comment: No, I use either one of them. It's a parameter which decides which one is used.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it temporarily with a check on the response like:

```
method, properties, body = channel.basic_get(queue=FromQueue)
if(method == None):
    ## queue is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check empty in body like this:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    decodeBodyInfo = body.decode('utf-8')
    if decodeBodyInfo != '':
        cacheResult = decodeBodyInfo
        ch.stop_consuming()
```

That so simple and easy to use :D

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using the `channel.consume` generator in a for loop, you can set the `inactivity_timeout` parameter.

From the pika docs,

```
:param float inactivity_timeout: if a number is given (in seconds), will cause the
method to yield (None, None, None) after the given period of inactivity; this 
permits for pseudo-regular maintenance activities to be carried out by the user 
while waiting for messages to arrive. If None is given (default), then the method 
blocks until the next event arrives. NOTE that timing granularity is limited by the 
timer resolution of the underlying implementation.NEW in pika 0.10.0.
```

so changing your code to something like this might help

```
        for method_frame, properties, body in channel.consume(queue, inactivity_timeout=120):

            # break of the loop after 2 min of inactivity (no new item fetched)
            if method_frame is None
                break
```

Don't forget to properly handle the channel and the connection after exiting the loop